# selected options for multi select Jquery in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Im using multi select Jquery (http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-
widget/demos/) How can I check in PHP (Controller) which option is selected?

This is my code in View:

```
 <select multiple="multiple" size="5">
    <?php

        foreach ( $this->restservice->getDepartments() as $department ) {
             echo '<optgroup label="' . $department->deptName . '">';
             foreach ( $this->restservice->getDepartmentsUsers( $department->deptName ) as $user ) {
                 echo '<option value="' . $user->{'email'} . '">';
                 echo $user->{'username'};
                 echo '</option>';
             }
        }

         echo '</optgroup>';
      ?>
  </select>
```

PS: Im using Codeigniter and I prefer to user foreach and fetch the value of selected options.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your `<select>` element a `name` attribute.

```
<select name="myselect[]" multiple="multiple" size="5">
```

Then when the form is submitted to a PHP file, the selected options will be in either $_GET['myselect'] or $_POST['myselect'] depending on the form's `method` attribute.

Comment: OP is using  `multiple`. This will only return one value.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `<select>` a name, suffixed by square brakets:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="5" name="myselect[]">
```

Then you can look for `$_POST['myselect']` (or `$_GET['myselect']`) as an array in your PHP script